# How can I Forward traffic through UBUNTU?

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, forwarding

I have a Ubuntu Desktop client and two Ubuntu server.

Ubuntu servers are two separate VPS in Germany and Netherland.

I need to route SSH traffic through Germany VPS, for example;

When I run **ssh root@GERMANY_VPS** on my client machine, it connects me to Netherland VPS.

In other words Germany VPS just forward SSH traffic and passes it to Netherland VPS.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you mean that you can't connect directly to the host in the Netherlands but the host in Germany can connect to this.

Just use the host in Germany as a jumphost:

```
ssh -J german_user@germany_vps dutch_user@netherlands
```

or add an ssh config....

```
Host germany_vps
   hostname germany_vps.example.com
   user german
   identityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_id.german

Host netherlands_vps
   hostname netherlands_vps.example.com
   user dutch
   identityFile ~/.ssh/rsa_id.dutch
   ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p germany_vps
```

Then simply....

```
ssh netherlands_vps
```

> When I run ssh root@GERMANY_VPS

Please don't do that.

Unless you know exactly what you are doing (and this clearly does not apply here) you should not allow root access via ssh.